# Get the menu items defined by hook_menu programmatically?

Tags: drupal, drupal-hooks

I'm having some problems defining my question properly in the title, but here is what I'm looking for:

I have defined some menu items in the `menu` function in my module, and somehow I would like to retrieve this data in the template files and use it to build a menu.

Is there any good way to do this, or am I approaching the issue in the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to call the menu function directly and build up a list of links:

```
$items = array();
foreach (mymodule_menu() as $path => $item) {
  $items[] = l($item['title'], $path);
}

// For Drupal 6
$rendered_menu = theme('item_list', $items);

// Or for Drupal 7
$rendered_menu = theme('item_list', array('items' => $items));
```